# Highcharts change plotBackgroundColor dynamically

Tags: background, highcharts

I try to change dynamically the plotBackgroundColor of my chart (after the highcharts generation). Before, and for a lot of attributes, I used (examples):

```
 chart.options.plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.format = '{y} meters'; \n";
 chart.options.tooltip.valueSuffix = 'meters'; \n";
```

So, with the same way, I want to change my plotBackground :

```
var gradient = {
  linearGradient: [0,400,0,0],
  stops: [
     [0, 'yellow'], 
     [1, 'black']
  ]
 };
 chart.options.chart.plotBackgroundColor = gradient;
```

But it doesn't work... Someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts v5+

Use [`chart.update()`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update). Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p5juc3no/1/

Snippet:

```js
chart.update({
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: 'transparent'
  }
});
```

---

Older versions of Highcharts:

Use `element.attr()` function: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/204/

Code:

```js
chart.plotBackground.attr({ 
  fill: 'white'
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't think to use "element" like this.

Comment: This does not seem to be working on latest version of highcharts. The solution tried in the question `chart.options.chart.plotBackgroundColor = ...` will work if it is followed by `chart.redraw()`

Comment: Updated answer for Highcharts v5+. Simply use `chart.update()` with new color.